# table cell not formatted properly in droidText

Tags: java, itext, android-droidtext

I created a table using droidText library, the cell within the table doesn't format the text properly, as the text goes over the cell border to the right.

[image]

As you can see, the text in the description cell goes over the border to the right. I'm using:

```
PdfPTable descriptionAndCalcContent = new PdfPTable(4); // 4 columns.
        descriptionAndCalcContent.setWidthPercentage(100);
        descriptionAndCalcContent.setSpacingBefore(10f);
        descriptionAndCalcContent.setWidths(new int[]{250, 50, 50, 50});
        descriptionAndCalcContent.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidth(0f);

        PdfPCell descriptionContent = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Descr iptionDescription Description Description Description Description" +
                "Descri ption" +
                "Descri ption" +
                "Descr iption" +
                "Description" +
                "Descri ption" +
                "Description" +
                "Descri ption" +
                "Descr iption" +
                "Description Descript ionDescriptionDescr iptionD escriptionD escript onDescription Description" +
                "DescriptionDes criptionDescripti onDescription" +
                "Descri ption" +
                "Desc ription" +
                "Descrip tionDe scriptionDescriptionDescri ptionDesc riptionDescri ptionDes cription" +
                ""));
description.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: droidText is obsolete and unsupported. Can you reproduce the problem with the official Android port: [iTextG](http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg)?

Comment: I figured it out, I just had to add indentation to the cell, that did the job. I just needed to go through the library documentation. Thanks for the response though :)